# Using Functions rather than one liners Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use Python functions to perform data preprocessing. I want to have efficient code. I have like 8 files that I am reading to load them and do some sort of analysis. How would one achieve that using a function and the .head() to read all the CSV files?

For instance instance I have loaded my data from One drive as follows.

```
 if 'myName' in user or user == '/Users/rick':   
    file1 = pd.read_csv(path + '/Data Exports/file1.csv')
    file2 = pd.read_csv(path + '/Data Exports/file2.csv')
    file3 = pd.read_csv(path + '/Data Exports/file3.csv')
    file4 = pd.read_csv(path + '/Data Exports/file4.csv')
    file5 = pd.read_csv(path + '/Data Exports/file5.csv')
    file6 = pd.read_csv(path + '/Data Exports/file6.csv')
    file7 = pd.read_csv(path + '/Data Exports/file7.csv')
    file8 = pd.read_csv(path + '/Data Exports/file8.csv')
```

How would I write a .head() to inspect the top 5 rows of all the loaded files?

Comment: Write a for loop.

Comment: In practice in order *only* want to inspect the top 5 rows of each file, one wouldn't really need to care about performance; the code would have to be spectacularly bad to make any noticieable difference in such a minor case. Having said that, what is the problem that you are *really* trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list or map comprehension would be better imo

```py
import glob

# list
datas = [
    pd.read_csv(f'{path}/Data Exports/file{i}.csv')
    for i in range(1, 9)
    if ('myName' in user or user == '/Users/rick')
]

# list whatever csv file name, will read all csv files
datas = [
    pd.read_csv(filepath)
    for filepath in glob.glob(f'{path}/Data Exports/*.csv')
    if ('myName' in user or user == '/Users/rick')
]


# map
datas = {
    "file%s" % i: pd.read_csv(f'{path}/Data Exports/file{i}.csv')
    for i in range(1, 9)
    if ('myName' in user or user == '/Users/rick')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When manipulating type-identical object, you may use a `list`

```
dfs = []
if 'myName' in user or user == '/Users/rick':
    for i in range(1, 9):
        dfs.append(pd.read_csv(path + f'/Data Exports/file{i}.csv'))

for df in dfs:
    print(df.head())
```

Comment: What if I have names for the files, Not file1, file2, file3, Maybe like clients, orders, invoices, pendinggoods?

Comment: use glob.glob method, see answer below

Comment: @DerrickKuria like all .csv in a folder ?